# How to fix the QGIS for Android GPS panel?

Tags: qgis, gps, android

I have installed GIS on my Samsung Galaxy S1, but I can't test the GPS.

I found how to turn the GPS on, but I cannot open the GPS panel to do it.
When I press `view->panels` nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my problem: There is a new version. It is described here: http://www.opengis.ch/2012/11/21/new-qgis-workaround-version/

Comment: Reading that post, there appears to be a newer "fixed" versions.  It looks like keeping an eye on [their development blog](http://www.opengis.ch/category/gis/qgis/android-qgis/)  might be best for keeping up with the latest and greatest releases.